# The set $C=\{f\in C([0,1]) : \int_0^\frac12f(x)dx-\int_\frac12^1f(x)dx=1\}$ has no element with minimal norm

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

*Let $C$ be a subeset of $C([0,1])$ of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\int_0^\frac12f(x)dx-\int_\frac12^1f(x)dx=1$$
Prove that:
$$f \in C \Longrightarrow ||f||_u>inf\{||g||_u : g \in C\}$$*

So the initial exercise asked to prove that $C$ is convex, closed and non-empty, which I proved by creating a functional linear like this: $L:C([0,1])\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ \ \ \ Lf=\int_0^\frac12f(x)dx-\int_\frac12^1f(x)dx)$, but I struggle to prove this statement. The suggestion that the exercise gives is to prove that if $f\in C$ then $||f||_u > 1$, that by intuition should be obviously true, but I don't know why.

A note:

$$||f||_=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$$

Comment: The main idea is that the way to make this functional as big as possible for fixed $\| f \|_u$ would be to have $f(x)=-\operatorname{sign}(x-1/2)$, but it can't be because that's not continuous. But you can regularize that by as little as you want and get something continuous.

Comment: It looks like you didn't understand the detail in the duplicate. In case you're still confused, I'll elaborate on what I said. Let $f$ be continuous with $\| f \|_u=1$. Let $\delta>0$ be such that if $|x-1/2|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(1/2)|<1/2$. Then $Lf \leq (1-2\delta) + \int_{1/2-\delta}^{1/2} f(x) dx - \int_{1/2}^{1/2+\delta} f(x) dx$. Now suppose $Lf$ were $1$, then the last two terms would have to be $2\delta$, then they would have to each be $\delta $, but they can't both be that; if one of them were $\delta$ then the other one would be no bigger than $-\delta/2$.